# Jquery active nav on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am trying to implement the active nav feature proveded here from jsfiddle

```
http:jsfiddle.net/SJkmh/15/
```

I want to implement it to my html, using the existing css and divs/ul li's but I keep failing.

I have a internal jquery-min.js call and worked with div (secion) IDs for each section. 
 Using `<section id"about></section>` gives me the wished scroll to effekt but the nav point does not get active.

Any help would be very appraciated.

Thanks in advance.

**The Div Nav currently looks like this:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="navi">
<ul>
<li class="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="speakers"><a href="#speakers">Speakers</a></li>
<li class="testimonials"><a href="#event">Testimonials</a></li>
<li class="event"><a href="#event">Event details</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html" id="pop-contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<a href="#" class="bt1">Book Now <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

**These are my css classes:**

```
.navi {float:left; padding:17px 0;}
.navi ul {float:left;}
.navi li {font-size:20px; line-height:2.4; font-weight:600; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px     rgba(0,0,0,0.2); margin:0 0 0 35px;float: left;}
.navi li {opacity:0.6;}
.navi li:hover {opacity:1;}
.navi li.active {opacity:1;}
```

**That's the Jquery code from jfiddle:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('section').waypoint(function(direction) {
        var activeSection = $(this);
        if(direction === 'down'){
            activeSection = $(this).next();
        }
        //activeSection = $(this);
        var sectionId   = activeSection.attr('id');
        $('ul li').removeClass('active');
        $('ul li.' + sectionId).addClass('active');
        console.log(activeSection);
    });
}); 

$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top - (target.height() / 5)
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Did you include [waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)?

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for your quick answer.
See the edit above with the jquery code in main.js now.
Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your script needs a external Jquery plugin.
[Waypoints](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.waypoints/2.0.2/waypoints.js).
You have to load this after loading JQuery.

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.waypoints/2.0.2/waypoints.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But it didn't work out for me...
I've found a easy solution without waypoints on github.
[LINK](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav)